Accessibility setup in Xcode 15
I'm trying to build a macOS Swift app that retrieves UI elements from another app using accessibility. I'm having permission issue despite checking 'AppleEvents' in Hardened Runtime. I also added 'NSAppleEventsUsageDescription' in the plist, but I still get permission issue. I am using this code to test it:
import SwiftUI
import Cocoa
import ApplicationServices

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var message: String = "Checking accessibility permissions..."

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Accessibility Test")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()

            Text(message)
                .padding()
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            checkAccessibilityPermissions()
        }
    }

    func checkAccessibilityPermissions() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let systemPreferencesApp = NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.systempreferences").first

            guard let systemPreferencesApp = systemPreferencesApp else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.message = "System Preferences is not running."
                }
                return
            }

            let pid = systemPreferencesApp.processIdentifier
            let axApp = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid)

            var attributeValue: CFTypeRef?
            let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(axApp, kAXFocusedWindowAttribute as CFString, &attributeValue)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if result == .success {
                    self.message = "Accessibility permissions are set correctly."
                } else {
                    self.message = "Accessibility permissions are not set correctly. Error code: \(result.rawValue)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


Accessibility API is not permitted in sandbox.

Turning it off worked, thank you!!
